# MomentJS code does not start a new week

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

```
$(function() {
function whenIsReset() {
    var now = moment.utc();
    var eventStart = moment.utc().day(2).hour(9).minute(00).second(00).millisecond(00);
    var eventStartNewWeek = moment.utc().day(-4).hour(00).minute(00).second(00).millisecond(00);
    var eventEnd = moment.utc().day(3).hour(9).minute(00).second(00).millisecond(00);
    var eventEndNewWeek = moment.utc().day(-4).hour(9).minute(00).second(00).millisecond(00);

    if (now.isAfter(eventEnd)) {
        eventStart = eventStartNewWeek;
        eventEnd = eventEndNewWeek;
    }
    if (now.isBefore(eventStart)) {
        $('#resettime').text('Resets ' + eventStart.from(now));
    }

    if (now.isAfter(eventStart) && now.isBefore(eventEnd)) {
        $('#resettime').text('Reset ' + eventStart.from(now));
    }
}

whenIsReset();    
setInterval(whenIsReset, 1000);
});
```

I am using 'MomentJS'.

The above code is supposed to:
  - Set 'Tuesday [9AM]' as the start
  - Set 'Wednesday [9AM]' as the end
  - If the time is before the 'start' then it shows the time to the 'start'
  - If the time is after the 'start' and before the 'end' then show time since     the 'start'
  - If the time is after the 'end' then it *SHOULD* set the 'start' and 'end' to the next week. (So it can be repeated).

Now, everything works. However, after the event has ended, it does not repeat and goes blank.

Answer (score 0):

This one is clasic. You only set the values eventStartNewWeek and eventEndNewWeek once, and therefore the value will not be recalculated when you assign them to a different variable.

```
eventStart = eventStartNewWeek;
eventEnd = eventEndNewWeek;
```

You could for instance create function and call it everytime you need to create a new eventStartNewWeek or eventEndNewWeek.

```
function eventStartNewWeek () { 
     return moment.utc().day(-4).hour(00).minute(00).second(00).millisecond(00); 
};

function eventEndNewWeek () { 
    return moment.utc().day(-4).hour(9).minute(00).second(00).millisecond(00);
};

// Assign them
if (now.isAfter(eventEnd)) {
    eventStart = eventStartNewWeek();
    eventEnd = eventEndNewWeek();
}
```